# Values used for my custom pipes is null

Tags: angular

Btw, I am a new to Angular 2. I have created a custom pipes as shown below. Then I used that pipes in my view as shown. The values used is retrieved via service. I have printed out the data retrieved from the service since I have successfully get the data from the service.

Below is code that does fetch the data from the service.

Now, what I want is to execute the codes that do the rendering in my view once the data is loaded. How to do that?

#### Angular2 Code:

```
@Pipe({name: 'values'})
export class ValuesPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any, args?: any[]): Object[] {

        if(!value)
            return;

        let keyArr: any[] = Object.keys(value),
            dataArr = [],
            keyName = args[0];

        keyArr.forEach((key: any) => {
            value[key][keyName] = key;
            dataArr.push(value[key])
        });

        if(args[1]) {
            dataArr.sort((a: Object, b: Object): number => {
                return a[keyName] > b[keyName] ? 1 : -1;
            });
        }

        return dataArr;
    }
}
```

#### HTML Code:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr *ngFor="let data of myPurchaseItems | values">
      <td>{{data.Purchase_ID}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

#### Angular2 Code:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._service.getMyPracticeTest(this.uid).subscribe(data => {  
        this.myPurchaseItems = data;
        console.log("DATA HERE: ", this.myPurchaseItems) 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just put an if statement in your html view, so that view is not rendered before data is retrieved, like so:

```
<table *ngIf="myPurchaseItems" class="table">
    <tr *ngFor="let data of myPurchaseItems | values">
      <td>{{data.Purchase_ID}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: wal, did this solution help you? :)